# python twisted read from one socket, write to another

Tags: python, twisted

So, I've found a number of examples using Twisted to create many simultaneous client connections, and how to support multiple protocols, and how to traverse many clients (http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#HowdoImakeinputononeconnectionresultinoutputonanother), but what I'm looking for is a code snipit which demonstrates how to read data in from a listener socket, do some manipulations, and write it out through a client socket.

I know I'm close, I just haven't nailed the pattern yet.

To be clear, I want to read a line from port 9000 -> pass to factory -> run algo -> write out port 9001 to a different process.

```
class ClientSideProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):
    def __init__(self, factory):
            self.factory = factory

def connectionMade(self):
    print "Made Connection to JoaC"

def connectionLost(self, reason):
    print "Lost Connection to JoaC"

def lineReceived(self, line):
    self.sendline(self.factory.tb.runAlgo(line))


class EmulatorFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
def __init__(self, sensorName):
    self.tb = tbg2(sensorName)

def startedConnecting(self,connector):
    print "Started to connect."

def buildProtocol(self, addr):
    print "buildProtocol called"
    return ClientSideProtocol(self)

def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
    print 'Lost connection.  Reason:', reason

def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
    print 'Connection failed. Reason:', reason

def main():
sensorName = "Test1"
mystuff = EmulatorFactory(sensorName)
reactor.listenTCP(9000, mystuff)
reactor.connectTCP(host = "localhost", port = 9001, factory = mystuff, timeout = 5)
reactor.run()
```

This is roughly what I have so far, am I in the ballpark?

Comment: Do you want separate 9001 connection for each Protocol instance, or shared connection in factory?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the same factory for your client and your server.  That means you'll have a hard time doing the right thing when data arrives either from client connections to your server or on your client connection from the remote server you've connected to.  They'll both be delivered to the same kind of protocol created by the same factory instance.  How will you decide what to do with the data?

I suggest using two different factories and probably two different protocols, instead.

Next, these lines don't implement the behavior you want:

```
def lineReceived(self, line):
    self.sendline(self.factory.tb.runAlgo(line))
```

This accepts data received from the remote side of the connection, passes it through `runAlgo`, and then sends the result of `runAlgo` back to the remote side of the connection.  It does not pass it off to a different connection.  You can tell it is the same connection because `self` was passed to `lineReceived`, telling you which protocol instance (and therefore which connection) the line was received on.  And then the code uses the very same `self` to send a line - sending it back to that same connection.  If you want to send it to a different connection, you need to call `sendLine` on a different protocol instance.